# Google App Engine: how to unescape POST body?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Newbie question...

I am using silverlight to POST data to my GAE application

```
  class XmlCrud(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):

      body = self.request.body
```

The data comes in fine but it is escaped like this:

```
%3C%3Fxml+version=%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-16%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CBosses+xmlns%3Axsi%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema-instance%22+xmlns%3Axsd
```

how do I unescape it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Hank.

The answer to your actual question, though, is that your example is URL encoded. To decode, replace each %XX with the character having hex value 0xXX, and + with space.

`urllib.unquote_plus` does this, and according to the docs it's in App Engine

urllib docs: https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

Statement that urllib is supported (there may be others): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html

Comment: Thanks!, I had looked at urllib briefly but assumed it could only do url decoding not HTML

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not encoding it in the first place if the body of the post is just an XML document.

Comment: Thanks, but then that leads to another question, how to POST from Silverlight without encoding (I am using WebClient)

Comment: I'm not really up on .NET anymore, much less Silverlight, but will http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstringasync(VS.95).aspx do the trick?

Comment: Thanks Hank that was what I was using, solution is to use WebRequest see full answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664270/google-app-engine-on-silverlight/1119848#1119848